# How to use JQuery to get information about certain tag?

Tags: jquery

For example, one of them has this:

```
<div id="hat" re="mouse" > text here </div>

$(.#hat).re = ??????
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$('#hat').attr('re');`

will get it

```
$('#hat').attr('re', 'blah');
```

will set it

Answer (score 2):

If you want to update the value of the re attribute simply write this:

```
$('#hat').attr('re', 'newValue');
```

Comment: the value would be $('#hat').attr('re')